# Mask UIView with UIImage by Keeping Transparent Area and Removing Coloured Area

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage, mask

I have an image:

[image]

That I would like to apply to a `UIView` to make the waveform (the transparent area) coloured.  I have tried the following:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "waveform")!

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))

let mask = CALayer()
mask.frame = view.bounds
mask.contents = image.cgImage!

view.layer.mask = mask
view.layer.masksToBounds = true
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
```

But this gives me the opposite effect, where the waveform is cut out:

[image]

I'd like the outside area of the waveform to be transparent, and the inside to be coloured.  I plan to place the `UIView` on top of another view, so I think it needs to be a mask.

I tried using `CIImage` to invert the transparent and coloured area as suggested in similar questions:

```
let cgImage = image.cgImage!
let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert")!
filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

mask.contents = filter.outputImage!.cgImage
```

...but this resulted in a blank `view` (transparent background).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: i think your looking for this [Reverse a CALayer mask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42238699/6689101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way...

```
func getImageWithInvertedPixelsOfImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: image.size)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, 2.0)
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.setBlendMode(.copy)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.setBlendMode(.sourceOut)
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.setFillColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.fill(rect)

    let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return result!
}

// I named your original image "WaveMask"
let iWave = UIImage(named: "WaveMask")
let invWave = getImageWithInvertedPixelsOfImage(image: iWave!)

// invWave is now Green where it was alpha, and alpha where it was gray
// and can now be used as a mask
```

Comment: Thank you!  I spent a good few hours trying to solve this, this works perfectly.  Time to read up on these functions :)